# Unable to get Ansible working on Azure Pipelines for configuration management

Tags: ansible, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, ansible-inventory

I am doing Infrastructure Provisioning with Terraform with Ansible doing config management.

Here is the **high-level overview**,

[image]

**Terraform** part is working as expected. The issue is with **Ansible** configuration management.

**Ansible configuration management job details are as below**:
[image]

**Error message** is below:

```
2019-02-24T13:10:12.4843263Z ##[section]Starting: Run playbook
2019-02-24T13:10:12.4991977Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-24T13:10:12.4992040Z Task         : Ansible
2019-02-24T13:10:12.4992109Z Description  : This task executes an Ansible playbook using a specified inventory via command line interface
2019-02-24T13:10:12.4992142Z Version      : 0.0.4
2019-02-24T13:10:12.4992171Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-02-24T13:10:12.4992237Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853835)
2019-02-24T13:10:12.4992267Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-24T13:10:14.0504658Z ERROR! the playbook: /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform could not be found
2019-02-24T13:10:14.0832289Z ##[error]Command ansible-playbook -i /tmp/ba06130c-26d3-4345-b658-3c3b728965f3inventory.ini /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/playbooks/common.yml  exited with code 1.
2019-02-24T13:10:14.0857295Z ##[section]Finishing: Run playbook
```

One thing I know for sure is, it works on the command line if I export the below variables,

```
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export AZURE_SECRET="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export AZURE_TENANT="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Note: I have created these variables in Variable group and made available for all pipelines.

The common.yml file does exist for sure, as I navigate and located it in Release definition. Not sure why during execution it is unable to locate.

On the command line, I run as below and it works so it should work on Azure Pipelines too?

```
ansible -i azure_rm.py ansible-inventory-test-rg -m ping
```

The file azure_rm.py script is at the location below:

**$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/scripts/azure_rm.py**

Name of the resource group is: **rg-app**

How to get Ansible to get working? Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The path `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/scripts/azure_rm.py` contains some white spaces which are unescaped. When you look at your output it says:

```
the playbook: /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform could not be found
```

There you see, that it's looking in the wrong path for the playbook. Try to remove the white spaces from the playbook path if that's possible or try to quote the `File Path` parameter with `""`.

Comment: Still not good,

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
ERROR! no action detected in task
The error appears to have been in '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/playbooks/common.yml': line 5, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
tasks:
 - name: Set timezone to A.U.S. Eastern Time (DST)
  ^ here

Comment: ##[error]Command ansible-playbook /home/vsts/work/r1/a/"_Terraform Build Phase"/drop/terraform/playbooks/common.yml -i azure_rm.py exited with code 4.
##[section]Finishing: Run playbook

Comment: Seems like it's unable to find the inventory script and therefore fails to run any task. Does it also say: 
"[WARNING]: Unable to parse azure_rm.py as an inventory source"

at the beginning of playbook execution? If so, try settings the "Inventory location" parameter to the ABSOLUTE path of the inventory. And when doing so, make sure to watch out for whitespaces.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't say anything about inventory source.
I verified the yaml has not syntax issues, I can get it working on my CentOS VM with same yaml. I am working on enabling WInRM on Remote servers.